# Точка в конце предложения после аббревиатур

Tags: пунктуация

Ставится ли точка в конце предложения после аббревиатур, в которых используется точка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря две точки подряд никогда не ставятся.
Правда явно это прописано только для аббревиатур типа "и т. д.", "и т. п.". Есть ещё какие-то случаи?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, не ставится, даже при использовании необщеупотребительных аббревиатур.

Answer (score 0):

Основой признак аббревиатур — слитное написание без точек. Архаичные формы надо, скорее всего, брать в кавычки. В сокращениях почти всегда ставится точка.